# rails with_options condition issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have 2 callbacks which are calling the same method and I want  to control them by same condition. Below the example code.

```
with_options if: :survey_enabled? do
  after_save: #some_method, unless: Proc.new { |role| role.role_name == "Manager" }
  after_save: #some_method, unless: Proc.new { |role| role.role_name == "Manager" }
end

private

def survey_enabled?
 Rails.configuration.survey_enabled
end

def some_method
 #my code
end
```

survey_disabled? is returning false am getting `undefined method after_save' for false:FalseClass`.

I tried calling the method in  a block(since without the block the methods gets called once class is initialized if am not wrong) like

```
with_options if: -> { survey_enabled? } do
  after_save: #some_method, unless: Proc.new { |role| role.role_name == "Manager" }
  after_save: #some_method, unless: Proc.new { |role| role.role_name == "Manager" }
end
```

But still am getting the same problem. May I know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `with_options` is, if you want to call series of operations on same object you can call it with `with_options`.

For eg: (From [railicasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/42-with-options))

```
with_options :if => :should_validate_password? do |user|
  user.validates_presence_of :password
  user.validates_confirmation_of :password
  user.validates_format_of :password, :with => /^[^\s]+$/
end
```

So here you are missing object on which operation has to be perform, which is **user** in above case.

```
with_options if: :survey_enabled? do
  after_save: #some_method, unless: Proc.new { |role| role.role_name == "Manager" }
  after_save: #some_method, unless: Proc.new { |role| role.role_name == "Manager" }
end
```

Same thing this message is saying `undefined method after_save' for false:FalseClass`. Block is trying to call after_save operation on false, which is object of FalseClass

hope it will help

Comment: So you mean passing the object will fix the problem? If so then I had given a try in that way as well